# How to display a tag's title inside the <h2> element with Ruby on Rails.

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and confused. I'm working my way through a tutorial where I'm supposed to display a tag's title in the h2 element by editing something in the file app/views/tags/show.html.erb. The h2 element currently looks like this:

```
`<h2 class="tag-title">
 def show
    @destination = Destination.find(params[:id])
 end
</h2>`
```

What do I need to add/edit here to display the tag's title?

Comment: You appear to be mixing up where the Ruby code goes. (It looks like you have a controller method in your html.)

Comment: Where might I find that? There are two separate html files: show.html.erb and index.html.erb.

Comment: Once you move that controller method to its proper place, you want to output something between the start/end heading (h2) tags.  If `@destination` holds your class instance, there may be an attribute which is suitable for a title.  If that attribute is `name`, or instance, you could access it in your view as `@destination.name`.

Comment: The controller file, ends with .rb, probably named `destinations_controller`, in the app/controllers directory.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the correct code. The h2 element should look like this:

`<h2><%= @tag.title %></h2>`

I'm still quite confused though. This tutorial is ridiculous, can't believe it's intended for people with no experience with Rails.